# Visual Studio StronglyTypedResourceBuilder - Set Culture for Current Object Only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedded-resource, multilingual, designer

I'm creating a multilingual control in VisualStudio 2010, .net 3.5.  Direction from above is to use a resource designer class created by the "StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", which basically protects the developer from (i.e. abstracts) the ResourceManager.GetString(String,CultureInfo) function.

One thing that I have noticed about the designer class is that the current Culture property is a static variable (internal static Culture) and therefore shared by everyone using that class.  Also, when accessing strings the getters do not let one specify a culture; it uses the static property.

Question:  Aside from reverting to the "ResourceManager.GetString" way of doing things...  is there any way that I can have one control get a string from the resource designer class in English, and another get a string in Spanish?  I want fine-grained control of which Controls show English and which show Spanish; that's my issue.

I understand that I can set the static property Culture before each access, but (a) that's a pain, and (b) with multiple controls hitting this resource file at the same time, thread safety and timing issues arise.